# Image callback c++ to c#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, callback, bitmapimage

I have the following problem:
I have a method in a c++ dll that uses some code from a hardware developer that captures an image in a 
"BITMAPINFO * info;"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183375%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

know I have to send it to a c# class that uses it, so I must send a callback to the c# class, right know I solve the problem sending the image to a file and reading the file form the C# class but I know it is not  the correct form to do it.

If someone knows how I can convert the bitmapinfo * to a byte * or how to implement the callback for a bitmapinfo to a managed code in c# it would be great.

Tanks for the time and sorry for my English ;)

Comment: the solution was using Pinvoke.net, its possible to use native c++ code for the marshal in c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was using Pinvoke.net, its possible to use native c++ code for the marshal in c#.
for get more information you can go to:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at4fb09f(v=vs.100).aspx
http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures.BITMAPINFO